# Safe Payment Processing with Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-processing, hangfire

I am attempting to find a method to safely process credit card payments inside `BackgroundJob`s with [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io) and my MySQL Database.

I have a `RecurringJob` that executes daily, that calls `ProcessPayments`, `ProcessPayments` is then intended to queue up jobs for each payment to execute the processing of the payment.

```
    public static void ProcessPayments(string input)
    {
        var payments = GetPaymentIds(input);
        foreach (var payment in payments)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ProcessPayment(payment.Id));
        }
    }
```

I would like to write this task so that if it fails it can pick up where it left off (as per Hangfire best practices), as well as ensure that one worker only gets one payment, **once.**

I was thinking of using `[DisableConcurrentExecution()]` and having the `RecurringJob` call a single function that grabs a payment, runs it, updates it, then moves on to the next. That way only one process could ever be running payments, however, I would lose the task concurrency offered by `BackgroundJob`.

Any suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please post your ProcessPayment method. Does it get payments from database? Or it just get payment from collection?

Comment: According hangfire documentation you should "Make your background methods reentrant" http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/best-practices.html.   So you should chose how to handle concurrency  in you code (for example using RowVersion or something like this https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)